# How to make ImageIcon work in all platforms

Tags: java, swing

I have made a simple UI but when I run the same code on the Mac the image doesn't appear.

I've tried it on Windows; it works, but on Mac it doesn't. I know about File.separator, but in ImageIcon it shouldn't be the case since a relative path is being converted into URL, and if I am not wrong, URL works on all platforms since its using forward slashes. I am really confused why its not working on Mac.

```
    JLabel lblDesigniteLogo = new JLabel();
    ImageIcon keyImage = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Images/designite_logo.png"));
    lblDesigniteLogo.setIcon(keyImage);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblDesignitelogo = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblDesignitelogo.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_lblDesignitelogo.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_lblDesignitelogo.gridx = 2;
    gbc_lblDesignitelogo.gridy = 0;
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblDesigniteLogo, gbc_lblDesignitelogo);
```

Comment: Maybe it is a problem of case-sensitivity, are the actual folder and file exactly named   "Images"  and   "designite_logo.png"   ?

Comment: what is your structure of the project?

Comment: What java version are you using? Method `getResource()` was revised in JDK 9 due to the introduction of the module system. In any case, have you tried simply printing the URL returned by method `getResource()`?

Comment: sorry for late reply, i am using java 12 and i dont think its case sensitive problem since its working on windows not on mac

Comment: and i am not sure how can i show project structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually due to the path of the image. When loading a resource from a package, your path should start with `/`. Instead of `"Images/designite_logo.png"`, it should be `"/Images/designite_logo.png"`. And of course the image should be in the proper package. You can test it yourself:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL imageUrl = Main.class.getResource("com/test/images/img.jpg");
        System.out.println(imageUrl == null); //Prints true

        imageUrl = Main.class.getResource("/com/test/images/img.jpg");
        System.out.println(imageUrl == null); //Prints false
    }
}
```

Where project structure is:

[image: structure]

Comment: oh ill try this out and will tell you asap